# Vivio product review pop-up scraping using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, review

I am trying to scrape the text of the reviews for a specific product for example (Banfi Brunello di Montalcino) on the Vivino.com site.
When you scroll at the bottom of the product link, there is a button 'Show more reviews'. I am **not able to click** on the button to continue scraping the information from the pop-up.

**Need help in understanding how I can modify this code, to ensure the scraper clicks on the button.**

Here is the snippet of the code that I have to try and click on the button.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.vivino.com/GB/en/banfi-brunello-di-montalcino/w/22917")


# get reviews

review_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="lowerSection belowTheFold"]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button')
review_link.click() 

try: #make sure review popup has loaded
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located\
        ((By.CLASS_NAME, 'allReviews__reviews--EpUem'))
except TimeoutException:
                print("Timed out waiting for review popup to load")
```

Comment: Is there an error message of some sorts?

Comment: //*[@id="all_reviews"]/div[2]/div[1]/button Try that xpath.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I tried that -> keep getting the same error: "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: @NilPujolPorta at the line for 'review_link', I get an error message saying unable to locate element - I believe my xpath is correct -> no sure why it's not able to identify it